# Parsing every file in a directory in python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

So I have this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for segment in root.iter("s"):
    for word in segment.iter("w"):
        print word.text,
    print "\n"
```

That will parse the xml file test.xml and print the parsed output. However, I have a huge number of these xml files that need parsing in a directory. How can I modify the code so that it goes through every file in the directory and applies this function to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [os.listdir(path)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)

It returns a list of all files in the dir.

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
listofxml = os.listdir("./")
    for xml in listofxml:
        tree = ET.parse(xml)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for segment in root.iter("s"):
                for word in segment.iter("w"):
                        print word.text,
                print "\n"
```

And if not all the files are xml, then you can split and check:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
listofxml = os.listdir("./")
    for xml in listofxml:
        format = xml.split('.')
        if format[-1] == 'xml':
            tree = ET.parse(xml)
            root = tree.getroot()

            for segment in root.iter("s"):
                    for word in segment.iter("w"):
                            print word.text,
                    print "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def printParsed(filename):
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for segment in root.iter("s"):
        for word in segment.iter("w"):
            print word.text,
        print "\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join
    mypath ='path/to/your/xml/files'
    onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
    for f in onlyfiles:
        # only does stuff if the file ends in xml
        if f[-3:] = '.xml':
            printParsed(f)
```

You would save the file, say as `parser.py`, and then run it like `python parser.py`. You can also drop the `if __name__ == "__main__"` section if you want.

Comment: When I run this, I get the following: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xmlparse.py", line 20, in <module>
    printParsed(f)
  File "xmlparse.py", line 6, in printParsed
    tree = ET.parse(name)
NameError: global name 'name' is not defined
O` I removed the `if f[-3:] =  '.xml' ": ` line because all the files are xml anyway.